# How to use for loop to print star for the size of an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am reading integer values from a text file and storing them in groups of 10 ex, 1-10,11-20 and like so in an array. I need to print a star for how many numbers are in each group on a line like this:

1-10 *******

11-20************

I have coded every thing but I can't get the output to print correctly. I was trying to use nested for loops but haven't had much luck.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int fileInts;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Histogram.txt"));
        int[] count = new int[10];

        // while loop
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            // find next line
            String num = scan.next();
            fileInts = Integer.parseInt(num);

            if (fileInts > 0 && fileInts < 11) {
                count[0]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 10 && fileInts < 21) {
                count[1]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 20 && fileInts < 31) {
                count[2]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 30 && fileInts < 41) {
                count[3]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 40 && fileInts < 51) {
                count[4]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 50 && fileInts < 61) {
                count[5]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 60 && fileInts < 71) {
                count[6]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 70 && fileInts < 81) {
                count[7]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 80 && fileInts < 91) {
                count[8]++;
            } else if (fileInts > 90 && fileInts < 101) {
                count[9]++;
            }
        }

        for (int s : count) {
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < count[c]; c++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println();
                    s++;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(count[]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're trying to implement a histogram, why inside the inner loop do you call `System.out.println()`?

Comment: i added that for the next set of stars will be on a different line

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use just

```
count[fileInts / 10]++;
```

instead of this veeery long if-else block. A division on an integer will always give you only the integer value, never a float. If you need the remaining value use modulo %.

To answer you question: your 2nd loop will only loop through the elements in the list, not each single character. You expect e.g. 21 to be 2 characters which is not the case, as you only count the integers - not counting the decimal numbers in each integer.

Comment: `count[10/10]++` is 2, which does not put it in the 0 index of the array as the user wants

Comment: `count[ (fileInts-1)/10 ]` would be more accurate, given the OP's requirements.

Comment: thanks i was just really more worried about the output

Answer (score 0):

Your loop needs to be this:

```
for (int s : count) {
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < s; c++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Think about the process in plain English:

1. For every integer in the range,

   1. Print a star
   2. Repeat until number of stars == current integer
2. Repeat loop

Other notes:

`System.out.println();` inside the inner loop prints a new line after each star. That's not what you want. You *do* want to print a new line after the stars for one range is printed though.

In you're loop, you are comparing the counter variable `c` to `count[c]`, which doesn't make sense. You need to compare it to the current integer you're working with, which you've defined as `s`.

---

When you're trying to reason through how a process will work in a program, it can help to write down an input set of data and work through it by hand. I know I learned the common sorting algorithms by shuffling a deck of cards and working through them.

Answer (score 0):

To loop over your array after you've counted the times each number within a range appeared, do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

But this has another issue, that you can't see which numbers you are counting. It might be an idea to make a String array with the number ranges:

```
String[] ranges = {"1 - 10: ", "11 - 20: ", ... , "90 - 100: " };
```

Then change you for loop to print out the appropriate range first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(ranges[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```